# How to get keyword args in Makefile script?

Tags: shell, makefile

Is there any way to get key word args in Makefile ?

i have tried giving args and accessing using $1, $2 etc, but how can we give it with a keywords.

Comment: You are not clear enough in your question, which is why it was closed as a dup (although I would have asked for clarification before closing it).  If you had provided an example of exactly what you wanted to do it would have been a lot better than this two-sentence question.  The term "key word args" doesn't mean anything to us; that term doesn't appear in the make manual etc.  If you want to see the make targets: `make foo` you want `foo`, then the duplicate question is the answer.  If you want to see variables make was given `make FOO=bar` and you want `FOO`, that answer won't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call just like env vars:

file syntax:

```
build:
    cat $(file)
```

command to run:

```
make file=my_file.txt
```